# Switch firstname and familyname colors in moderncv

Tags: color, moderncv

In the moderncv casual theme, in the header, the family name has a darker color than the first name. How can I make it the other way around, and more generally, set each name to a color of my choosing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For recent versions of `moderncv` you need to use

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\color{color2!50}\@firstname}{\color{color2}\@firstname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\color{color2}\@lastname}{\color{color2!50}\@lastname}{}{}
```

(Thank you, Gonzalo Medina!)

---

**The following applies only for version `2008/06/17 v0.7` of `moderncv`**

---

The names are typeset by the commands

```
\firstnamestyle
\familynamestyle
```

which are defined in `moderncv.cls` as follows

```
\providecommand*{\firstnamestyle}[1]{{\firstnamefont\color{firstnamecolor}#1}}
\providecommand*{\familynamestyle}[1]{{\familynamefont\color{familynamecolor}#1}}
```

You can adjust them to your liking via

```
\renewcommand*{\firstnamestyle}[1]{{<whatever>#1}}
\renewcommand*{\familynamestyle}[1]{{<whatever>#1}}
```

If you just want to switch the colors, your call would be

```
\providecommand*{\firstnamestyle}[1]{{\firstnamefont\color{familynamecolor}#1}}
\providecommand*{\familynamestyle}[1]{{\familynamefont\color{firstnamecolor}#1}}
```

Comment: I don't seem to be able to locate `\firstnamestyle` or `\familynamestyle` in `moderncv.cls`. Perhaps those were the settings in previous versions?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Mine is `2008/06/17 v0.7` with TL 2013 on Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Ah, that explains it. Mine is 2013/04/29 v1.5.1 (Tex Live2013).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina In the current CTAN version the color of first and last name is buried deep inside `\makecvtitle`. I will try to adjust this using `xpatch`.

Comment: Yes, I know. In the current version you need to do `\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}
  {\color{color2!50}\@firstname}
  {\color{color2}\@firstname}
  {}
  {}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}
  {\color{color2}\@lastname}
  {\color{color2!50}\@lastname}
  {}
  {}` If you want to, you can add this to your answer.

Comment: I forgot to mention: you need `etoolbox` for the patch.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I added your proposal to my answer.