# Different name and surname colors in moderncv classic

Tags: moderncv

I would like to stylish the name and surname like the casual moderncv theme: name and surname of different colors.
I tried [Switch firstname and familyname colors in moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172865/switch-firstname-and-familyname-colors-in-moderncv), but doesn't work for me. 
MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}       


% moderncv themes
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'banking', 'oldstyle' and 'fancy'
\moderncvcolor{red}                             

% adjust the page margins
\usepackage[scale=0.75]{geometry}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\color{color2!50}\@firstname}{\color{color2}\@firstname}{}{}
\patchcmd{\makecvtitle}{\color{color2}\@lastname}{\color{color2!50}\@lastname}{}{}


% personal data
\name{Mickey}{Mouse}

%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
%            content
%----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\makecvtitle

\end{document}
```

I tried to change `\makecvtitle` with `\makecvhead` because the command to be patched seems to be `\makecvhead` actually, but neither. Whats wrong? Did the moderncv style definition changed in some other point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use this code:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_US
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,roman,english]{moderncv}        % possible options include font size ('10pt', '11pt' and '12pt'), paper size ('a4paper', 'letterpaper', 'a5paper', 'legalpaper', 'executivepaper' and 'landscape') and font family ('sans' and 'roman')
\moderncvstyle{classic}                             % style options are 'casual' (default), 'classic', 'oldstyle' and 'banking'
\moderncvcolor{orange}                               % color options 'blue' (default), 'orange', 'green', 'red', 'purple', 'grey' and 'black'
%\nopagenumbers{}                                  % uncomment to suppress automatic page numbering for CVs longer than one page
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                        % if you are not using xelatex ou lualatex, replace by the encoding you are using
\usepackage[scale=0.75,a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{lipsum}                                % Used for inserting dummy 'Lorem ipsum' text into the template
\usepackage{color}
%------------------------------------------------------------
%            personal data
%------------------------------------------------------------
\firstname{Giacomo}
\familyname{\color{red}Alessandroni}
%\title{Ph.D. Complexity science, field of research: digital signal processing}
```

and the result it is:

[image: My CV with surname in red]